# Taking two elements from an array and adding them, then adding them back into the array

Tags: arrays, recursion, f#, pattern-matching, calculator

Im trying to create a calculator in f# using two arrays, one which stores the numbers and the other to store the operator symbols. I need the symbols array to pattern match the symbol and depending on the operator take the first two elements from the array and do the operation and add the new number into the head of the 2nd array.

```
open System

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
printfn "%A" argv

let Add x y = x + y
let Sub x y = x - y
let Div x y = x * y
let Mul x y = x / y

printfn "1 > Calculator \n2 > Load from txt file"

let chosenIn = Console.ReadLine();

//This is where I need to do the operation and after call the sum function 
//again until there's only one element left in the number array
let rec sum num (numArray : int[]) sym (symArray : string[]) () =



let rec calc () = 
    printfn "Enter Sum"
    let input = Console.ReadLine()
    let intInput = input.Split()
    let numArray = [|for num in intInput do
                        let v , vp = System.Int32.TryParse(num)
                        if v then yield vp|]

    let symbolArray = [|for symbol in intInput do
                        match symbol with 
                        | "+" -> yield symbol
                        | "-" -> yield symbol
                        | "/" -> yield symbol
                        | "*" -> yield symbol
                        | _ -> ignore 0|]

    calc()

match chosenIn with
| "1" -> calc()
| "2" -> printfn "File"
| _ -> printfn "Invalid"

0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: The question is ill-defined, and the few code fragments help little to clarify what possibly the question could be. The current code accepts "1 2 3 4" as an input, just as it accepts "+ - /" or "1 2 / + 3 * *" Please clarify what the expected behaviour in those cases is.

Comment: One of the main problems with this is that for `+`, `-` and `*` the signature is `int -> int -> int` but for `/` it can be `int -> int -> int` or `int -> int -> float` which is why if you look at certain examples you will see the answer leaving out `/`. Also the input should be into one stack with both the operators and operands combined so that [reverse polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) can be used.

Comment: I wanted the user to input a simple sum such as "4 + 2", and the application to parse the string into a input string array and then parse the input string array into two arrays, one for the numbers and one from the symbols such as 
numArray = [| 4; 2;|]
symArray = [| "+"|].

then call a the sum function which take the two arrays as parameters.
the function would look at the first symbol in the symbol array and from that symbol determine what operator to use on the first two elements in the num array. and return a new num array with the new calculated number.

Comment: Why an array for the numbers, and for the operators? This would make everybody think that you also need to handle cases where you have >1 operators, for example. Do you _only_ expect inputs like "number op number", or could there be anything else?

Comment: Even if the user enters more then one operator such as "5 + 3 - 1" the sum function is recursive which means that it will call through more then once. For example
"5 + 3 - 1" -> [5 ,3, 1] and [ "+", "-"] and after the first call it will create two new arrays [8, 1] and ["-]. the program will see that there's still two numbers and will run through again creating leaving just one number left which will be the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to the answer @Liam Donnelly posted to his own question: I'll leave aside questions like "is that really the best way of solving the problem", just commenting on how to better write the code you currently have.

Array slicing and concatenating the way you are doing it here can be written as

```
let newNumArray = Array.append [| result |] numArray.[2..]
```

However, I would use F# lists rather than arrays for your task. With lists, you can do pattern matching to access the first 2 elements. Pattern matching, in my view, wins over direct indexing because you can directly encode corner cases, and get the F# compiler to remind you of corner cases. Do the same thing for the operators. You can do both operators and operands in the same go. It will then look something like this:

```
let rec sum2 (numArray : int list) (symArray : string list)  =
    let newNum, newSym = 
        match numArray with
        | [] -> failwith "No numbers left to process"
        | arg1 :: [] -> failwith "There's only one number left to process"
        | arg1 :: arg2 :: args -> 
            match symArray with
            | op1 :: ops ->
                let result = 
                    match op1 with
                    | "+" -> Add arg1 arg2
                    | "-" -> Sub arg1 arg2
                    | "*" -> Mul arg1 arg2
                    | _ -> failwithf "Operator not recognized: '%s'" op1
                // Return the result, concatenate the non-processed 
                // numbers. Return the non-processed operators
                result :: args, ops
            | _ -> failwith "I've run out of operators?"
<snip>
```

Also, returning a "default result" if you don't recognize the operators is something that I consider very risky (even though the practice is rather widespread)

If you use lists (F# lists, that is), you can directly access the elements at indices 1.. via `head`: `let newSymArray = symArray.Head` or use `List.head`

Take a step back each time you see yourself writing a `for` loop in F#. They are cumbersome to write and error-prone. Most of the typical use-cases for loops are covered by F# library functions, so have a good read through those. Your printing loop can be written way shorter by doing:

```
newNumArray
|> Seq.iter (printfn "%i")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make the function which performs the task I needed for it to do and I'm sure there's a much more code efficient way of taking the first elements of the arrays by using Array.copy with filters but I'm new to f# so I just it the way I was confident with

```
let rec sum (numArray : int[]) (symArray : string[])  =
    let result = match symArray.[0] with
                 | "+" -> Add numArray.[0] numArray.[1]
                 | "-" -> Sub numArray.[0] numArray.[1]
                 | "*" -> Mul numArray.[0] numArray.[1]
                 | _ -> 0

    let newNumArray = [|
                        for i = 0 to numArray.Length - 1 do
                            if i = 0 then yield result
                            if i > 1 then yield numArray.[i]|]

    let newSymArray = [|
                        for i = 0 to symArray.Length - 1 do
                            if i > 0 then yield symArray.[i]|]

    if newNumArray.Length > 1 then
        sum newNumArray newSymArray
    else
        for i = 0 to newNumArray.Length - 1 do
            printfn "%i" (newNumArray.[i])
```

Comment: Your solution is still not making good use of F#. I've added an alternative answer and comments below.